# Azure Boards Task linked to deleted branch

Tags: git, azure-devops

I've linked an Azure DevOps item to a feature branch af a Azure Repo,
to make it easier for the user to follow up as the code evolves.

Now the feature has been merged to the main branch.

According to our branching policy I'm supposed to delete the feature branch.

What's going to happen to the link between the Boards item and the deleted branch?
Will it simply disappear?
Will I lose the connection between code and the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two situations.

**The first** is the work item linked to the branch and the work item has already been saved.

In this situation, everything between the work item and the branch will be removed(the link).

**The second** is the work item linked to the branch but the work item has not been saved.

You will be unable to view it:

[image]

But if you restore the branch like this:

[image]

It will be able to view again:

[image]